# Nifi executegroovyscript not able to read html from parameter context

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I have a variable called html stored in a parameter context variable, the value of this variable is a short html script. I am trying to access that value from inside a executegroovyscript, i have tried a few options and from the documentation this seems like the correct line

`String myVariable = context.newPropertyValue('#{html}').evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue()`

However the processor through an error that stops me being able to run it

````
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
 startup failed: Script1dc359b3.groovy: 23: Unexpected character:
 "\" @ line 23, column 42. ariable (0 = context.getProperty("<!DOCT^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: 
Unexpected character:
 "\" @ line 23, column 42. at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder.createParsing FailedException(AstBuilde
r.java:4376)
at me org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder.convertException(AstBuilder.java:261) at ...```

I am unsure what else to try to remedy this so any help would be greatly appreciated.
````

Comment: sounds like it's already evaluated before execution (which is not good). try: `String myVariable = '''#{html}'''`

Comment: another idea: `String myVariable = context.newPropertyValue('#'+'{html}').evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue()`